# How to make a function in a base class that takes in a subclass of itself as a parameter?

Tags: c++

Please forgive me if i'm missing some obvious thing - I am currently a pretty new to C++ and still learning it, thanks in advance.

So I have two functions, say, Base class ANIMAL, subclass SHEEP and subclass COW.

```
#include <iostream>

class Animal
{
public:
    void Noise(/*Subclass input here*/)
    {
        // Somehow call said subclass Noise() function
    }
};

class Sheep : public Animal
{
    void Noise()
    {
        std::cout << "Baa" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Cow : public Animal
{
    void Noise()
    {
        std::cout << "Moo" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Animal* animal = new Animal();
    Sheep* sheep = new Sheep();
    Cow* cow = new Cow();

    animal->Noise(/*Subclass input here, for example: sheep*/);

    return 0;
}
```

How would I input the subclass into the Base class then call the subclass function? I'm unsure whether this is even possible but worth a shot :)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You don't need subclasses as parameter, you can just use a `virtual` function, and the subclass function will be automatically called even if you use a base class pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `virtual` to utilize polymorphism and avoid having to pass the concrete object as an argument to the base class.

```
#include <iostream>

class Animal
{
    public:
        virtual void Noise() = 0;
};

class Sheep : public Animal
{
    public:
        void Noise() override
        {
            std::cout << "Baa" << std::endl;
        }
};

class Cow : public Animal
{
    public:
        void Noise() override
        {
            std::cout << "Moo" << std::endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    Animal* animal = new Sheep();

    animal->Noise();

    delete animal;

    animal = new Cow();

    animal->Noise();

    delete animal;
}
```

The result is:

```
Baa
Moo
```

Example: https://rextester.com/TQK18582

As per comments bellow, this is a quick example that implements the above code using CRTP: https://rextester.com/TWMLD53466

Comment: `virtual void Noise();` should be even pure virtual, because an implementation rarely would make any sense.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: That's very true. But his code was instancing an Animal object which wouldn't be able to instance with a pure virtual function. And that's the reason I removed that part but forgot to add the pure virtual back in. :-P

Comment: An alternative solution to using virtual would be to utilize static polymorphism via [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). This is more efficient but also a more.. rigid.. solution.

Comment: @JoakimThorén: Yes... but have a read at the question "I am currently a pretty big noob at C++ and still learning it..". Do you really want to start talking on Templates let alone CRTP? haha.

Comment: @JoakimThorén How would you define the base class pointer to enable both instantiations at the same pointer type using a CRTP?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I don't think that's possible. In the code posted in the question, the cow and sheep variables are declared like so: `Sheep* sheep = new Sheep()` and `Cow* cow = new Cow()`. In this case, CRTP could work instead of virtual methods.

Comment: @JoakimThorén So what's the gain over using simple virtual poöymorphism then. Sure you could add another layer of indirection with the CRTP using virtual polymorphism again, but I don't see any advantage doing so.

Comment: @ConstantinosGlynos I don't think it's harmful to mention that there exists an alternative to virtual methods, should OP need it. But yes, I agree, it's probably not something that OP should delve into yet. However, not all readers are pretty big noobs on C++ so I don't think it's irrelevant to mention CRTP.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The gain to use CRTP over polymorphism is that in the former you need no vtable.

Comment: @JoakimThorén: The problem is that it's not just CRTP that could work in this case. The code in this question doesn't have much which means that there are many different ways to tackle this design. Rightfully said, CRTP is one of them, but I thought it would be too much for someone new to C++. Anyway, I think you're right about not being harmful to show that method too. I'll knock something up..

Comment: Here's a quick example of the above code implemented using CRTP. https://rextester.com/TWMLD53466